# Firefox automatically closing form straight away

Tags: php, ajax, oscommerce

**EDIT : Fixed, I just removed the tables and made it tableless, it will require abit of css to sort the layout but is working cross browser, thank you everyone.**

I have a really weird issue, I'm trying to do a AJAX quick order form in oscommerce. All is going well apart from this code:

```
while ($sql_results = tep_db_fetch_array($sql_query)) {

    $sout2 = "<tr>";
    $sout2 .= '<form id="pp'. $sql_results['products_id'] . '" method="get" action="quickorder.php"></tr><tr>';
    $sout2 .= "<td valign=\"top\" width=\"100\"><b><a href=\"" . tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO, 'products_id=' . $sql_results['products_id']) . "\">" . $sql_results['products_model'] . "</a></b></td>";
    $sout2 .= "<td valign=\"top\" width=\"300\">" . $sql_results['products_name'] . "</td>";
    //$sout .= "<td valign=\"top\" width=\"100\">" . tep_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $sql_results['products_image'], $sql_results['products_name'], 50, 50) . "</td>";
    $sout2 .= "<td valign=\"top\" width=\"150\"><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"pid\" name=\"pid\" value=\"" . $sql_results['products_id'] . "\" /><input id=\"pqty\" name=\"pqty\" type=\"text\" value=\"1\" /></td>";
    $sout2 .= "<td valign=\"top\" width=\"50\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add\" /></td>";
    $sout2 .= "</form>";
    $sout2 .= "</tr>";
    echo $sout2;
}
```

This makes firefox close the form tags straight away:

```
<form id="pp266" method="get" action="quickorder.php"></form>
```

IE does the forms correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure but it doesn't seem like it is valid to put a form inside a `tr`. I think the only valid elements are `td` and `th`...

Comment: If it works in IE and not in FF it's more likely you screwed it up then FF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine your markup thoroughly. You have something like

```
<tr><form ...></tr>
```

This closes the tr right away, causing all nested elements to close as well (FF behaviour, IE behaves differently). So, replace

```
$sout2 .= '<form id="pp'. $sql_results['products_id'] . '" method="get" action="quickorder.php"></tr><tr>';
```

with

```
$sout2 .= '<form id="pp'. $sql_results['products_id'] . '" method="get" action="quickorder.php"><tr>';
```

Also, it might be a good idea to move the form outside the row, as some browsers do not allow `form` tag to appear inside the `tr`, only `td` and `th`.

Comment: Hi, I have moved the form outside of the tr tags and still have the same problem.

Comment: Well, this means that you have to place your form outside the `table` tag. Actually, it's strange that you create a from inside each row.